# If $(x_n)_{n\ge0}$ is positive and increasing, find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_1^n+...+x_n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> If $(x_n)_{n\ge0}$ is positive and increasing, find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{x_1^n+...+x_n^n}$.

Any solution or help is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record, this is the fourth question with zero context you post today. My suggestion: stop the flow and start adding some personal input.

Comment: @Did Stalker much? Anyway. I'll jeep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: @theSongbird Nah, many high rep users simply remember particular users (usually through experience with them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us call $L=\lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n$ ($L$ could be $+\infty$) and $a_n=\sqrt[n]{x_1^n+\cdots+x_n^n}$.

We have, because $x_n>0$ for all $n$
$$x_n=\sqrt[n]{x_n^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{x_1^n+\cdots+x_{n-1}^n+x_n^n}=a_n$$

and, as $x_n$ is increasing:
$a_n=\sqrt[n]{x_1^n+\cdots+x_n^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{x_n^n+\cdots+x_{n}^n}=\sqrt[n]{nx_n^n}=\sqrt[n]{n} \cdot x_n$

So we get $$x_n\leq a_n \leq \sqrt[n]{n}\cdot x_n$$

Now note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1$, so $a_n$ is between two sequences whose limit is $L$. Using the squeeze theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=L=\lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n$$