# Limit of $\sqrt[n]{5^n + 11^n + 17^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ where $a_n = \sqrt[n]{ 5^n+11^n+17^n}$. I am really stuck on this as I should not be allows to use exponential and logarithmic properties to solve this. Through graphing I have found that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 17$, which can intuitively be understood as the $17^n$ absorbing the other terms, but I have not idea how to prove it.

I though of using Monotone convergence theorem but I am not able to show that $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$. Could I get a hint ?

Comment: Hint: $$
a_n  = 17\sqrt[n]{{1 + \left( {\frac{5}{{17}}} \right)^n  + \left( {\frac{{11}}{{17}}} \right)^n }}.
$$ The expression under the root is always between $1$ and $2$.

Comment: More of this kind: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2533102/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128024/42969

Comment: Gary's hint is the standard approach for such exercises. Usually, factoring out the term with the fastest growth rate solves the problem.